# Freemarker - querying a Map<Long, ...>

Tags: hashmap, key, freemarker, long-integer

In Freemarker, I have a `Map<Long, ...>` (the keys are `Long`).

Freemarker's `map[key]` only supports string keys. So I have tried `map?api.get(0)` but that behaves like the value is not there. Yet if I do

```
<#list statsForThisBox as projID, val>
Project #${projID?c} has value: <b>${val???c}</b>
</#list>
```

Then I see that the entries are there.

Project #64256 has value: true
   Project #0 has value: true

**Is there a way to query a `Map` for a `Long` key?**  (Other than creating a special function in Java.)

Edit: I am thinking of something like

```
map?api.get("java.util.Long"?new(123))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `Map.get(Object)` signature doesn't help FreeMarker to choose the right numerical type (and because Java `equals` is `false` among different `Number` subclasses, even if their values are really the same), you have to tell FreeMarker what type you want: `map?api.get(123?long)`.